# Example Javascript to convert to AMD

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

Are there any example javascript/dojo projects that are designed specifically for practicing AMD formatting?

Or, does anyone know of some simple projects that would be a good starting point to practice AMD? I have read through the tutorials but they lack this stype of exercise and I don't have a lot of ramp up time for AMD to create and reformat my own javascript projects

Comment: Perhaps start with the [RequireJS examples](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html)

Comment: They already look formatted, such as the multipage app example